# PHP check the last two characters in variable

Tags: php, variables

I would like to check if the last two characters in variable are a determinate characters..

**For example:**

```
$variable="2016-01-07";
```

I would like to check if `$variabile` that the last two words there is `"07"`

Comment: Your string looks like a date, so you have to query for the (day / month) what it is. You can do this in many ways...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$variable = "2016-01-07";
$lstTwo = substr($variable, -2);

if ($lstTwo == "07"){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check using `substr()` function

```
$variable="2016-01-07";
$newstring = substr($variable, -2);
if($newstring == "07") {
 // success
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [substr](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) which has the arguments `string $string , int $start [, int $length ]`. Manualy says

> If start is negative, the returned string will start at the start'th
>   character from the end of string.

So this

```
$variable="2016-01-07";
$lastChars = substr($variable, -2, 2);
if($lastChars === "07"){
...
}
```

or just this

```
$variable="2016-01-07";
$lastChars = substr($variable, -2);
if($lastChars === "07"){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look up substr, it does exactly what you've asked.

```
$variable = "2016-01-07";

if (substr($variable, -2, 2) == "07") {
// Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$check = substr($variable, 9, 2);
if ($check=='07') {
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use

```
$variable = "2016-01-07";

if (substr($variable, -2) == "07") {
...
}
```